# Get a list of envelopes that are close to expiration via DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

My company uses [DocuSign API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/) to automate document-related tasks.

Via the API, I need to retrieve all envelopes that are expiring soon. Similar to what the DocuSign UI has in the screen below but for all users:

[image]

Can somebody point me in the right direction -- which API endpoint/method I need to use to get all envelopes that are about to expire? Is there any way to use DocuSign Connect to trigger a callback from DocuSign for each document that is about to expire?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your API call (GET to /envelopes endpoint)

```
folder_ids=expiring_soon&folder_types=normal,inbox,sentitems&include=recipients,powerform,folders,delegations,workflow&include_purge_information=true&query_budget=10
```

Remember to also have `from_date` and `to_date` parameters

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/

Also, the way I found this out for you was by trying it from the web app and recording API logs, Suggest you try that too as it will mean you can find it yourself. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJYTDcc7cZw